# How to solve a second order ODE without first order and zeroth order derivatives?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think I did  a mistake here in trying to solve

$y''-k^2=0$

where k is some constant.

I did

$y''=k^2\rightarrow y'=xk^2+C\rightarrow y=\frac{k^2}{2}x^2+Cx+D$

which does not give an exponential solution. Alternatively, I tried:

$y''=k^2\rightarrow y=Ce^x$, but with the $k^2$ term I am not sure.

What is right here, and how to complete it?

Thanks

Comment: Why should there be an exponential solution?

Comment: The DE doesn't have an exponential solution.  If you had $k^2y$ then it would.

Comment: Thanks! So the first solution is the correct one?

Comment: It is correct. And you mixed something up. The HOMOGENEOUS equation $y''=0$ has an exponential solution: The characteristic equation gives $c_1\exp(0)+c_2\exp(0)x$. Then you have to make an ansatz that resembles the RHS.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, it was the reason of why I searched for an exponential solution, not recalling this you added